# Transformation of Dimensions

Tags: dimensional-analysis, unit-conversion

I'm reading *Applied Dimensional Analysis and Modeling* by Thomas Szirtes and struggle with the transformation of dimensions. In particular, given
$1\,\textrm{m} = x\,\textrm{cm}$, its easy to see that $x=100$. Yet, when I attempt manipulate terms as follows, I get nonsensical results

\begin{align}
1\,\textrm{m} &= x\,\textrm{cm} \\
1\,\textrm{m}\,\textrm{cm}^{-1} &= x\,\textrm{cm}\,\textrm{cm}^{-1} \\
1\,\frac{\textrm{m}}{\textrm{cm}} &= x \\
x &= 0.01,
\end{align}

which is clearly wrong. Where/what is the error? Alternatively, multiplying by unity seems to work

\begin{align}
1\,\textrm{m} &= x\,\textrm{cm}\,\frac{\textrm{m}}{\textrm{cm}} \\
1\,\textrm{m} &= x\,(0.01\textrm{m}) \\
x &= 100,
\end{align}

Comment: Your first batch of logic is fine up until the last line. Double check the value of m/cm.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment, to me that reads meters per cm. i.e. how many meters per cm and that's 0.01, no? cm/m reads to me how many cm per m which would be 100?

Comment: @CodyMcNary No, $\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{cm}$ means how many centimeters in a meter. If you have $100$ cookies and $10$ people to divide them among, you calculate $100/10$, which means "how many cookies in a single person" or, more colloquially, "how many cookies does a single person get?"

Comment: @Yejus, thanks for the reply. Yet, I'm totally confused. If we take speed: km/h which reads (to me :) "how many kilomenters per hour". So subsituting words (km:m, h:cm) should give "how many meters per cm"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason for your confusion is that you are talking about two different meanings of the words "per" and "in", which depends on whether you are comparing like quantities or unlike quantities. When you say $x/y$ and both $x$ and $y$ have the same dimensions (in your case, length), then the meaning is how many of $y$ can $x$ fit.

If you want to avoid language games altogether, you can simply re-express either $\mathrm{m}$ or $\mathrm{cm}$ in terms of the other: $1 \mathrm{m} = 100 \, \mathrm{cm}$ or $1\,  \mathrm{cm} = 10^{-2} \, \mathrm{m}$: and get the answer $x = 100$.

On the other hand, when $x$ and $y$ are unlike quantities (different dimensions), then it makes no sense to talk about how many of one fits in the other: we would be comparing apples to oranges. In such a situation, the meaning of $x/y$ as "$x$ per $y$" is different than in the previous case. It should be interpreted not as a how many of $y$ goes into $x$, but rather as "how many of $x$ given $1$ of $y$", or something else of that sort.

Answer (score 0):

Look this is a very simple issue. **cm** is short for **centi-metre**, which is **defined** as **$\frac1{100}$ metre**. Nothing else needs to be said. So $\frac{\text{m}}{\text{cm}} = \frac{\text{m}}{\frac1{100}\text{ m}} = 100$.

Same for **all other** prefixes for SI units. For example $\text{kg} = 1000 \text{ g}$.